# Heroku + Amazon RDS backups == downtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

On Heroku, I realize our app goes down for a few minutes once a day or so. I contacted Heroku support abut this and they suspect the issue is with Amazon RDS doing backups. So I checked on this one day and found out that RDS was indeed trying to do a backup. But why does Heroku + RDS have to put our app down?

Which is quite unacceptable. Backups are good, but downtime for backups does not play out nice. Is there a solution to this? Or should I consider using another database service?

Is anyone else on RDS and Heroku experiencing the same downtime when Amazon RDS does backups?

Comment: FYI we are using heroku with their postgres and its working perfectly with no down time and backups are also being getting captured.

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, we are using MySql on RDS at the moment. Might be a pretty tough job to migrate from MySql to PgSql

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem with RDS from what I understand.  There are [some workarounds](http://blog.masterbranch.com/post/660261241/backing-up-rds), but for me, the simplest approach would be to consider using Postgres instead.

If you're on Rails, most of this hard work will be done via ActiveRecord or similar (unless you're writing a lot of raw PG specific code)

Comment: I'm a fan of Postgres. Unfortunately, at the time, Heroku only offered dedicated plans starting at $200 / month. And they still do, with the exception of Postres addon services like Xeround. Which IMO is on the same price range ($200)

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to experience latency spikes during the backup window, though I personally haven't experienced downtime of my app as I had in the past when I maintained my own MySQL server and ran mysqlhotcopy or mysqldump.

Though it requires an increased budget (x2), utilizing the RDS Multi-AZ setup will ensure that backups are created using the database clone in the other Availability Zone. This in theory should entirely eliminate any downtime or latency.

This FAQ page should give you a clearer picture: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#88

Comment: Yipes! The Multi-AZ setup sounds interesting. But x2 doesn't. At this rate, might be more suitable to go on a Heroku Postgres dedicated plan, since the price will almost be identical